# Laravel Parameter Grouping (and/or where)

Tags: laravel

I upgraded **Laravel** to **version 7**, and when I do a query like this:

```
$users = User::where('name', '=', 'John')
           ->where(function ($query) {
               $query->where('votes', '>', 100)
                     ->orWhereNull('title');
           })
           ->get();
```

it doesn't work as expected, and I got this error  `[SQL Server] Must specify table to select from`

because the SQL should be like this:

```
select * from users where name = 'John' and (votes > 100 or title is null)
```

but when I debug the returned query it shows like this:

```
select * from users where name = 'John' and (select * votes > 100 or title is null) is null
```

The above query it just an example of my complex query, and I have a lot like this query in all of my project so I don't need a replacement, I just need to know how to fix it as it worked fine before upgrading

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whereRaw` for the alternative method, for example

```
$users = Table::whereRaw(" name=? AND (votes=? OR title=?)", array(?,?,?))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$users = User::where('name', '=', 'John')
           ->where(function ($query) {
               $query->from('users')
                     ->where('votes', '>', 100)
                     ->orWhereNull('title');
           })
           ->get();
```